# Did Haman actually try to rape Esther?

Tags: megillat-esther, haman, esther--the-woman

In the book of Esther, [verse 7:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.7.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), most translations translate נָפַל as fallen, subdue, force or violate. A few actually translate it as "rape".

Was this just a euphemism or could Haman have, as a dying, desperate man literally raped or attempted to rape Hadassah, or was he simply prostrate at her feet and begging for his life? Could Esther have been left unguarded briefly by her eunuchs?

I did not see this question specifically addressed. Thanks in advance for your thoughts and answers. First-time poster in this sub forum. Blessings!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya! Editing in a source that translates נפל as rape would be make the question more compelling. Hope to see you around!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jimmy Mac and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 5):

Those translations are not accurate. נָפַל means "fell" and refers to Haman falling. The simple meaning (as given by Ibn Ezra) is that he fell before Esther to plead for his life. (If it said "fell upon" that might be different, but it doesn't.)

Achashverosh however interpreted it as if he was trying to rape Esther. It isn't so reasonable, but then he was never assumed to be the most reasonable person.

Answer (score 2):

Its an interesting question.

At face value, Haman had fallen at the feet of Queen Esther to beseech her mercy.

When the king returned from the garden, and was full of anger, he retorted to Haman:

[וַיֹּאמֶר הַמֶּלֶךְ הֲגַם לִכְבּוֹשׁ אֶת־הַמַּלְכָּה עִמִּי בַּבָּיִת](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.7.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%BC%D6%B9%D7%90%D7%9E%D6%B6%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%B6%D7%9A%D6%B0%20%D7%94%D6%B2%D7%92%D6%B7%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D6%B4%D7%9B%D6%B0%D7%91%D6%BC%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A9%D7%81%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%D6%BE%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D6%B4%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%AA)
" Do you intend to conquer the queen in my own palace?”

The translation of the word לִכְבּוֹשׁ as explained by [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.7.8?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9Cand%20the%20land%20is%20conquered) is in the theme of "conquering".

It seems therefore, that the king was retorting how dare Haman attempt to attack the jewish people, of whom the Queen is a member, "do you intended to conquer the queen in the kings palace" would mean, does Haman have the audacity to attempt to kill the queen!